# Ruby on Rails, ошибка при тесте - TasksController GET #index returns a success response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

У меня есть вот такой простой тест.

```
require  'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe TasksController, type:  :controller  do
describe "GET #index" do
it "returns a success response" do
  get :index
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
 end
 end
end
```

К такому котроллеру.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
expose :task, -> {current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])}
expose :active_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: false).order('priority ASC')}
expose :completed_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: true).order('priority ASC')}

def index
render json: {active: active_tasks, completed: completed_tasks}, status: 200,  each_serializer: TasksSerializer
end

def show
 render json: task, status: 200, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end

def create
task = current_user.tasks.create(task_params)
render json: task.id, status: 201, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end

def update
if task.update(task_params)
  render json: task, status: 200
else
  render json: task.errors, status: 422, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end
end

def destroy
if task.destroy
  return head(:ok)
else
  return head(:bad_request)
end
end

def batch_destroy
tasks = current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
end

private

def task_params
params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :due_date, :active)
end
end
```

После команды rspec в консоли, вылетает вот такая ошибка при прохождении теста:

```
Failures:

1) TasksController GET #index returns a success response
 Failure/Error: expose :active_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: false).order('priority ASC')}

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:3:in `block in <class:TasksController>'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/flow.rb:67:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/flow.rb:67:in `handle_options_override'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/flow.rb:55:in `block in handle_flow_method'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/flow.rb:85:in `fetch_ivar'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/flow.rb:53:in `handle_flow_method'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/flow.rb:25:in `method_missing'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/exposure.rb:181:in `block in attribute'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/context.rb:58:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/context.rb:58:in `fetch_value'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/context.rb:23:in `get'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/decent_exposure-3.0.2/lib/decent_exposure/attribute.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in expose!'
 # ./app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:7:in `index'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /home/milestep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.28294 seconds (files took 1.54 seconds to load)
 10 examples, 1 failure

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:4 # TasksController GET #index returns a success response
```

Подскажите что нужно изменить для прохождения теста, буду очень благодарен, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать необходимо следующее:

1) Создать файл хелпера для проверки контроллеров с devise со следующим содержанием

```
# spec/support/controller_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

2) Раскомментировать одну строку в `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

3) Добавить в Ваш тест контроллера одну строку

```
before { sign_in User.create(email: 'foo@example.com', password: '12345678') }
```

В результате вышеприведенных действий, перед запуском тестов контроллера будет выполнятся авторизация и, как следствие, метод `current_user` не будет возвращать `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Текст ошибки говорит сам за себя:

```
Failure/Error: expose :active_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: false).order('priority ASC')}
NoMethodError: undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass
```

Ваш экшн контроллера предполагает наличие залогиненного пользователя (current_user), а в вашем тесте его нет. Чтобы тест прошел, в нем надо создать пользователя и залогинить его. Как это сделать - зависит от того, чем вы пользуетесь, фабриками или фикстурами, и что вы используете для аутентификации пользователей. Если devise - то у него под это есть специальный хелпер `sign_in(user)` для тестов.

Ну а вообще контроллер должен не падать с ошибкой в таком случае, а редиректить на страничку логина. Devise это опять же умеет